# How superficial an artery has to be for pulse to be measured manually?

Tags: blood-circulation

Why arteries  pulse? How superficial an artery has to be for pulse to be measured manually?

Comment: They pulse because the blood flow follows the heart beat. I do not think there is a specific depth that they need to be to be measured, the ones from the wrist and neck are usually used.

Comment: The larger the artery, the deeper it can be and still be palpated, e.g. the descending aorta is palpable in the abdomen of the average person.